# Is there a better way to create max url page numbers based off known total count of items?

Tags: python

I'm trying to see if there's a way to shorten this code. Say this is a job site and it shows that there are a total of 138 jobs available with 20 jobs listed on each page. It takes the known count of total jobs and divides that by 20/page to come up with a total number of pages to iterate through. It works but I feel like there's a better way to do this.

```
url = "https://fake-job-site.com/search?"
count = 138

if count % 20 == 0:
    pages = count / 20
else:
    pages = count / 20 + 1

for page in range(1, pages + 1):
    new_url = url + "&page=" + str(page)
    print(new_url)
```

Result:

```
https://example-url.com/search?&page=1
https://example-url.com/search?&page=2
https://example-url.com/search?&page=3
https://example-url.com/search?&page=4
https://example-url.com/search?&page=5
https://example-url.com/search?&page=6
https://example-url.com/search?&page=7
```

Comment: Why would you want to shorten that code? There's only 10 lines of it. It's fine.

Comment: @zvone: You're right. I tried out the other options and this turned out to be the most simple and fastest way. I sometimes doubt myself and think there's probably a better way I could write things. Thanks

Comment: BTW, you could do this: `pages = (count - 1) // 20 + 1`. It may be a bit less readable at first, but it is shorter and it is a fairly common pattern for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify by using ceiling division and `str.format` (or f-strings in Python 3.6+), and by adding 1 in the loop.

```
def ceildiv(a, b):
    """Ceiling division of a by b."""
    return -(-a // b)

url = "https://fake-job-site.com/search?"
count = 138

pages = ceildiv(count, 20)

for page in range(pages):
    new_url = '{}&page={}'.format(url, page+1)
    # new_url = f'{url}&page={page+1}'  # Python 3.6+
    print(new_url)
```

Output:

```
https://fake-job-site.com/search?&page=1
https://fake-job-site.com/search?&page=2
https://fake-job-site.com/search?&page=3
https://fake-job-site.com/search?&page=4
https://fake-job-site.com/search?&page=5
https://fake-job-site.com/search?&page=6
https://fake-job-site.com/search?&page=7
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorten in terms of lines taken:

```
>>> count = 138
>>> a = [print("https://fake-job-site.com/search?"+'&page='+str(page+1)) for page in range(count//20 if count//20 == count/20 else count//20 + 1)]

https://fake-job-site.com/search?&page=1
https://fake-job-site.com/search?&page=2
https://fake-job-site.com/search?&page=3
https://fake-job-site.com/search?&page=4
https://fake-job-site.com/search?&page=5
https://fake-job-site.com/search?&page=6
https://fake-job-site.com/search?&page=7
```